# Testing wall clock time based algorithms

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I'm currently maintaining an algorithm that uses wall clock time to make various decisions (eg. which solutions are quick to calculate which are taking too long and need to be scrapped).

When trying to test the algorithm, results can be slightly different each time due any number of variables such as machine load, operating system scheduling, IO etc.

What is the standard approach for testing such a system? Something like CPU instructions executed was one idea I had, however I'm not sure how practical that is on a modern multi-core x86 processor.

The fall back plan is to add increments to an internal counter and change the limits of the algorithm to try and match the performance of the existing wall clock version. However it will involve a lot of trial and error so I'd like to know if there is an easier way before I start going down that path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple but crude option is to "abstract away" the wall time retrieve logic.

Say, use a class `WallTime` with a `GetTime` method and use this throughout the application.

There are two "providers" of time that this class can use. One is the RT clock in the system.

The other simply returns values from a pre-recorded list.

You record the first pass through the algorithm and store the values returned by `GetTime`.
These values will form the "pre-recorded" list of values for the second "time provider".

Assuming the second run will make calls to `GetTime` in the exact same order you can simply return the same time values as in the first run :)

You can also edit the list if you want to adjust some timings.
You can also have multiple stored list, to simulate different hardware.

Example:

Suppose the algorithm works like this:

1. `GetTime` -> returns T1 from the clock
2. Call a function X
3. `GetTime` -> returns T2 from the clock
4. Decide what function to call next (e.g., `Y`) based on (T2 - T1)
5. `GetTime` -> return T3 from the clock
6. Call the function `Y`
7. `GetTime` -> return T4 from the clock
   ...

After you save T1, T2, T3 and T4 in a list you can replay the above run exactly (with regard to the values returned by `GetTime`).

This solution will fail if the function that is executed at step 6 (which is one that your algorithm selects based on performance) is not the same in the second run even if the (T2 - T1) time difference is the same, i.e. it depends on a variable, non-time related parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I like @Andrei's solution, but from what you described it seems like your algorithm may not always make the timing calls in the same sequence. In that case, I might make a simple `WallClockTimer` class that could record various durations by name/enum (with methods like `startTimerFor(SOME_KEY)` and `getElapsedTimeFor(SOME_KEY)`). Your algorithm will collaborate with this timer to make its runtime decisions. To test those decisions, you can make a `MockWallClockTimer` to return pre-specified durations for given keys.